# Access Violation

Tags: c++, debugging, memory

Greetings everyone, going to need some help in clearing this exception.

I get the following when debugging my compiled program in Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0:

```
Loaded 'ntdll.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\tsappcmp.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', no matching symbolic information found.
First-chance exception in SA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation.
```

Here are the relevant screenshots from the debugger.

Showing ostream.h:

http://img237.imageshack.us/my.php?image=accessviolation.png'>http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/1116/accessviolation.th.png' border='0'/>

Showing main.ccp:

http://img509.imageshack.us/my.php?image=accessviolation2.png'>http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/3619/accessviolation2.th.png' border='0'/>

I've tried to scour my code for null pointers and have also tried to ignore the exception with no luck. Here are the three main components of my script:

main.ccp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "SA.h" 

using namespace std; // For the use of text generation in application


int main() 
{
    SimAnneal Go;

    cout << "Quadratic Function" << endl
         << "Solving method: Simulated Annealing" << endl;

    cout << "\nSelect desired Initial Temperature:" << endl
         << "> ";
    cin >> Go.T_initial;

    cout << "\nSelect desired number of Temperature Iterations:" << endl
         << "> ";
    cin >> Go.N_max;

    cout << "\nSelect desired number of step Iterations:" << endl
         << "> ";
    cin >> Go.N_step;

    cout << "\nSelect desired Absolute Temperature:" << endl
         << "> ";
    cin >> Go.T_abs;

    Go.LoadCities();

    Go.Initialize();

    Go.SA();

    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

SA.h

```
    #ifndef SA_H
    #define SA_H


class SimAnneal {

        double S_order [15];        
        double S_trial [15];        

        int SwapNum1;
        int SwapNum2;

        double CityArray [15][15];

        double E_initial;
        double E_current;

        double T;

        void Metropolis (double, int, int);
        void Next_State (double, int);
        double Schedule (double, int);
        double ObjFunction (double CityOrder []);

        void EquateArray ();
        void OrderInt ();
        void OrderTrial ();
        void OrderList (double array[]);

        void WriteResults (double, double, double, double, double);

      public:
        int N_step;
        int N_max; 
        double T_initial;
        double T_abs;

        void SA ();
        void Initialize ();
        void LoadCities ();
    };


    double Random_Number_Generator(double nHigh, double nLow);


#endif
```

SA.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>          
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>           
#include <cstdlib>          

#include "SA.h"

using namespace std;


void SimAnneal::SA() 
{
    T = T_initial;
    E_current = E_initial;


        for ( int N_temperatures = 1 ; N_temperatures <= N_max ; N_temperatures++ )
        {
            Metropolis(T, N_step, N_temperatures);
            T = Schedule(T, N_temperatures);

        if (T <= T_abs)
            break;
        }

    cout << "\nResults:" << endl
    << "Distance> " << E_current << endl
    << "Temperature> " << T << endl;

    OrderList(S_order);
}

void SimAnneal::Metropolis(double T_current, int N_Steps, int N_temperatures)
{
    for ( int i=1; i <= N_step; i++ )           
        Next_State(T_current, N_temperatures);      
}

void SimAnneal::Next_State (double T_current, int i) 
{
    OrderTrial();

    double EXP = 2.718281828;

    double E_t = ObjFunction(S_trial);
    double E_c = ObjFunction(S_order);

    double deltaE = E_t - E_c;                              
        if ( deltaE <= 0 )
        {    
        EquateArray();
        E_current = E_t;
    }
        else
        {
        double R = Random_Number_Generator(1,0);
        double Ratio = 1-(float)i/(float)N_max;         
        double ctrl_pram = pow(EXP, (-deltaE / T_current));

            if (R < ctrl_pram*Ratio)                        
            {   
            EquateArray();
            E_current = E_t;
        }
        else 
            E_current = E_c;
    }
}

double SimAnneal::Schedule (double Temp, int i) 
{
    double CoolingRate = 0.9999;

    return Temp *= CoolingRate; 
}

double SimAnneal::ObjFunction (double CityOrder []) 
{
    int a, b;

    double distance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15 - 1; i++)
    {
        a =  CityOrder [i];
        b =  CityOrder [i + 1];

        distance += CityArray [a][b];
    }

    return distance;
}

void SimAnneal::Initialize () 
{
    int a, b;

    double distance = 0;

    OrderInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15 -1; i++)
    {
        a =  S_order [i];
        b =  S_order [i + 1];

        distance += CityArray [a][b];
    }

    E_initial = distance;
}

void SimAnneal::EquateArray () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        S_order [i] = S_trial [i];
    }
}

void SimAnneal::OrderInt () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <15; i++)
    {
        S_order [i] = i;
    }
}

void SimAnneal::OrderTrial () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        S_trial [i] = S_order [i];
    }

    SwapNum1 = (int)Random_Number_Generator(15, 0);         
    SwapNum2 = (int)Random_Number_Generator(15, 0);

    for (int n = 0; n <= 100000; n++)                       
    {
        SwapNum2 = (int)Random_Number_Generator(15, 0); 

        if ( SwapNum1 != SwapNum2 )
            break;
    }

    S_trial [SwapNum1] = S_order [SwapNum2];
    S_trial [SwapNum2] = S_order [SwapNum1];
}

void SimAnneal::OrderList (double array[]) 
{
    cout << "Array List : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << " > " << array[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "End of array" << endl;
}

void SimAnneal::LoadCities () 
{
    int x, y;

    for (y = 0; y < 15; y++)                    
    {    
        for (x = 0; x < 15; x++)            
        {      
            if (x == y)
            {   CityArray[x][y] = 0.0;  
            }
            else if (x != y)
            {   CityArray[x][y] = Random_Number_Generator(7, 1); 
            }
        }  
    }  

    for (y = 0; y < 15; y++) 
    {    
        for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) 
        {      
            if (y > x)
                CityArray[y][x] = CityArray[x][y];
        }  
    }  
}

double Random_Number_Generator(double nHigh, double nLow)
{
    double fr = ((rand() % ((int)nHigh*1000 - (int)nLow*1000 + 1)) + nLow) / 1000;

    return fr;
}
```

Any Assistance would be much appriciated. I'm all out of ideas myself.

Comment: This compiles and runs fine on VS2008. Don't think the problem is with the code unless it's a VC6 compiler bug.

Comment: Can you please provide the input values that you are using when the crash happens ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't compile one module with one compiler and another with the other?  Do a clean and see if the error goes away.  Also looks like you aren't checking input ranges (T_Initial > 0 and T_abs < 0 could be bad if T_current = 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted wouldn't even compile:

1)

```
cin >> Go.Write;
```

There's no such variable in the `SimAnneal`  class.

2)

```
Go.SA(Go.Write)
```

Your `SA` method doesn't accept any parameters.

Another thing is, why don't you run your project in debug mode directly in VC++ 6.0? The VS on the screenshots is clearly 200*X*.

According to the screenshots, you're crashing on the line:

```
cout << "Quadratic Function" << endl
     << "Solving method: Simulated Annealing" << endl;
```

Which doesn't make much sense, unless your output stream is mutilated in some way. Have you tried watching the console before the crash occurs?

Comment: Appologies. That was an old version of the main.cpp file. Updated it as it should be. I thought it odd to be crashing on those lines too. I've tried to remove them and it'll just crash on the next set of cout outputs. Removing them all results in a (NTDLL.DLL) Access Violation

Answer (score 2):

a =  S_order [i];
b =  S_order [i + 1];
distance += CityArray [a][b]; <--- This looks suspicious. When i = 14, b = 15...clearly outside the range...
my 2 cents

Comment: But i is less than 15 - 1, which is less than 14. Hence I can't be higher than 13.

Comment: Thats was the issue last time I had this error, before I re-wrote the entire program with classes. But i will only ever reach 13 as the if condition states: for (int i = 0; i < 15 - 1; i++). hence maximum i=13 and maximum b=S_order[14], which was perfectly legitimate until today :S

Comment: The problem is not the 14 here, is the value that comes out of S_order[14].

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really look like you are doing anything too fatal in your code that I can see, have you tried removing lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://bytes.com/groups/net-vc/535224-whats-first-chance-exception-how-do-i-fix

But I think the answer is what someone else said - the distance = line

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    S_trial [i] = S_order [i];
}

// ....
for (int i = 0; i <15; i++)
{
    S_order [i] = i;
}
```

Both loops are going too high. Change them to 14 instead of 15.

Comment: Not really, since:

        double S_order [15];            
        double S_trial [15];

Answer (score 0):

you can always put try { } catch(...) { } blocks around code and compile with /EHa

to identify the problem areas